# Screen resolution changes after playing game

Tags: opengl, games

I installed SuperTuxKart and I played this game in fullscreen. After closing the game, my screen resolution was changed. This happens every time I play any game in fullscreen mode. Windows can restore the default resolution after closing any game.

Is it a bug or a normal thing? How can I fix it?

Comment: it's a bug, report it at launchpad please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly a bug in your video driver or an Ubuntu one. If you have a good video card, try to use the same screen resolution in the game as in your desktop.

Comment: that solution will never work in long terms.

Comment: If it is a bug in the video driver it's in every Linux video driver ever built.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run:

```
xrandr -s 1 && xrandr -s 0
```

To make sure that game doesn't do it again:

1. Make a folder with that game's name.
2. Make a `.sh` file in that folder.

   Example code below. Change the game's name for the particular game:

   ```
   flobopuyo
   xrandr -s 1 && xrandr -s 0
   ```
3. Save the file and close.
4. <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the file and go to *Properties* → *Permissions* → *Allow executing as a program*.
5. Use Alacarte to change application to launch with `.sh` file you created.
6. Delete the launcher for that game from the panel.
7. Go to menu and search for the game.
8. Add to panel if you wish (<kbd>right-click</kbd> → *Add to favorites*).

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
xrandr --auto --rotate normal --pos  0x0
```

or if you can get into your Start menu, look for the word "display". It should be under System or Prefereneces.

I'm currently looking for a way to set this to a hotkey. So you might want to checkout [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594283/how-can-i-have-my-display-settings-automatically-restored-after-i-play-a-full-sc).